# Binding Context initialize component issue

Tags: c#, xamarin

So what I have is 2 objects I need both object to be initialized but as soon as the app starts. currently I'm having my `MainWindowViewModel` initialized but my `Budget` only initializes after I click one of the buttons on my app ie click the save button to save info a user enters. Below is my `MainPage` code. If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong with this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new Budget();
        BindingContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Below is an image of the app it should show £0 under total amount & have 0 In Entry.

[image]

All binding is correct in the .cs Its jdefinitely the `MainPage()` where the issue lies

Comment: you know that with this code you will no longer to interact with Budget instance because you don't keep reference to it?

Comment: Why are you assigning BindingContext twice?  Your page only has one BindingContext property.  As @selvin says, you are not maintaining a reference to your Budget object after you create it.

Comment: @Jason What would my best approach be, create a new TabbedPage for Budget?

Comment: Could it work now ?

Answer (score -1):

```
Budget BudgetVM { get; set; }
MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BudgetVM = new Budget();
    BindingContext = ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

Comment: I have absolutely no clue how/where/etc your are trying to use `Budget`.  You only posted 2 lines of code, and I've pointed out the obvious problem with those two lines of code.  If you want more help you need to provide more relevant context about the problem.

Comment: Fair! I have updated with a screenshot If you need to see anything else just let me know. I am convinced its the MainPage()

Comment: that is absolutely useless for explaining what the problem is.  We should not have to play 20 questions with you every time you post in order to understand what problem you are trying to solve.   Why don't you just make Budget a property of your MainPageViewModel?